# SqlConnection Runtime error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Here i have write the coding for image upload control.but getting some RUNTIME error.error sows in SqlConnection place
first i have
1.Image name box - Textbox 
2.Image Upload control - asp imageupload control
3.Upload button

ERROR :Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.

Code Below

```
public partial class ProfileDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
  string connStr =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
//SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=CHATHU-LAPTOP;Initial Catalog=ProfilemgtDB;User ID=sa;Password=sa123");
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("images/");
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
        if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".png")
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(path + FileUpload1.FileName);
            string name = "~/images/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
            string s = "Insert into Profile values('" + TextBox12.Text.Trim() + " '.'" + name + "' )";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Write("File Uploaded");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("You can upload only JPG & PNG");
        }

    }
    else {

        Response.Write("Please Select File");
    }
    }
}
```

ERROR :Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.

Comment: which line is throwing that error?

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);

Comment: Probably nothing to do with your error, but this code is a disaster waiting to happen. NEVER use string concatenation to create sql values to pass in an INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT etc operation

Comment: another issue is response.write. you using webforms so use the server controls to manage displaying messages.

Comment: I'm a beginner.i wrote this code using youtube video.Help me to solve this runtime issue.

Comment: Or can you please show me the good example

Comment: Which are the value in the var `connStr`. The string with the connection it's correct?

Answer (score 0):

Nimesh,

I do not see anything wrong in the code. However, you may want to check if your **web.config** contains the same connectionStrings name as mentioned in your code (which is ConnectionString).

Also, refer the following links

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=4287517

http://forums.asp.net/t/1757347.aspx/1

Hope this helps.